# Executing root-required script from non-root user

Tags: python, bash, cgi, sudo, sudoers

I'm using the Apache CGI mod to allow execution of python scripts via HTTP(S) request. The problem is that the script I want to be executed, **backup.py**, at one point executes a subprocess call where a **mysqldump** command is being piped into **sudo -i**. The problem is that the CGI "user", **www-data**, doesn't have root access, and I certainly don't want to give it that in general, just for this specific task. How can I allow **www-data** to perform only a **mysqldump** command only under **sudo -i**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of elevating the permissions for a specific script, is to use the sudoers file.

Create a file containing the script you wan't to execute with root permissions, lets say at `/path/to/script.sh`.

Then, edit the `sudoers` file with `sudo visudo`, and add the following line:

```
www-data ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh
```

where the the usernames and the path are set as appropriate.

Comment: This was close, however there's a nuance! 

Because the script contains subprocess calls, the sudo access isn't inherited by them. 

This means that I use your solution but instead of giving root access to the script, I gave root access only for the subprocesses it needs. This prevents someone modifying the script file later and abusing that root access (it is accessed by the web anyway).

So:

    ***%www-data       ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash, /usr/bin/python***

Comment: @EschersEnigma: But then you are giving access to *any* bash or python script, and not only the one you created. It would be better to isolate the commands that need root access to a separate script, and give permissions for that. Btw I think subprocess should normally inherit the permissions from their parent process, not sure why you needed to add them specifically. Perhaps you are calling it with `bash script.sh` instead of `path/to/script.sh`?

Comment: It's being called by CGI, so I couldn't even begin to tell you whether CGI runs it with bash or path. As for the other problem, there could be refinement however I've no idea how I would specify.